# Python regex to find symbol digit symbol

Tags: python, regex

I wrote this regex in Python and tested it out on regex101, but it is still not working the way I want:

```
((^[-\/\\\(\)\s\,\&\.]+)?([0-9]+)([-\/\\\(\)\s\,\&\.])+)
```

What I am trying to find is the pattern where the string optionally starts or ends with one of these symbols, and has ONLY digits in the middle:

```
-/\()& .
```

This list includes dash, forward slash, back slash, parenthesis, ampersand, blank space, and period.  A search should return true if the string contains ONLY digit is in the middle with optional punctuation at the beginning and/or end of the string.

This regex seems to work for most cases, but fails if I add a letter into the digits in the middle. It still ends up returning True. What should I do to this regex so that it only returns true for cases where there is symbol (optional), all digits, symbol (optional)?

Cases where it should return True:

1. symbol + digits i.e. (9672
2. only digits i.e. 20427304 or 8
3. digits + symbol i.e. 345--
4. symbol + digits + symbol i.e. (67-.

Case where it should NOT return True (because of the 'y' in the string):

(678983y733)..

Comment: You definitely miss a `$` or `\Z` at the end of the pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things in your regex that need to change.

- First of all, you have WAY too much escaping going on there, which makes it super confusing to read.
- Secondly, You have weird stuff happening with the parenthesis. You don't need anything to completely surround the regex, because  `$0` already will return that.
- Your last char class is not optional in your regex.
- You need to surround everything with `^$` in order to ensure that the string isn't a partial match.

Here's what I came up with:

```
^([-/\\()\s,&.]*)([0-9]+)([-/\\()\s,&.]*)$
```

Note that having `([something]+)?` is equal to `([something]*)`, but the latter is more readable.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that `]+)?` and `]*)` are equivalent.

Comment: @ChrisNielsen: They might in this particular case but in general they are of course not.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is `re.fullmatch`.

```
import re
ponct = '[' + re.escape('-/\()&') + ']*'
p = re.compile(ponct + '[0-9]+' + ponct)
```

Then `p.fullmatch('(678983y733)')` will return None, 
and all your other examples will return a match.

Comment: When I try to run your code example, I get this error:
`AttributeError: '_sre.SRE_Pattern' object has no attribute 'fullmatch'`

Comment: You must have a python version < `3.4`, that's all. But the `re.escape` function may still be of some use for clarity.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks. I am using 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

This allows you to find them embedded in a string, not just at the start.  The ? allows zero or one symbol.  Change this to * if you want zero or more leading/trailing symbols.

```
([-\\\/\&\.]?)\b([0-9]+)\b([-\\\/\&\.]?)
```